# robot with scissor lift legs, problem with constraints and parenting

Tags: rigging, constraints

I'm trying to make a robot with legs like a scissor lift, so that it can stretch up. I'm using constraints to control the legs stretching. the rotation is controlled with a copy rotation constraint and the position is controlled using a transform constraint. (left unstretched leg, right stretched leg)

[image]

The problem lies with when the leg is bent as the scissor lift part does not rotate correctly. the bending was done by rotating a parent (left pic). another problem is when bones are applied to the mesh, the positioning and rotation gets messed up (right pic)[image]

i think the issue could that i should have applied the constraints after the parenting and bones or there is something i'm missing.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I am in a similar boat.