# scissor car lift animation rig objects not following path

Tags: rigging

i can not make the piston follow the cylinder correct way
and i can not hook the lift been to the bottom platform

i put a link for a youtube video where i explain
https://youtu.be/Y07GYkT2fMo

hope someone can help me

Comment: Is this based on a real scissors lift? Do you have an accurate blueprint? Can you provide the blend file? In order to animate this properly the dimensions need to work out. You could also think about using empties at your pivot points and parenting the arms to the empties.

Comment: Similar questions for reference: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78170/precise-mechanical-rigging-intuitive-method/  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79800/robot-with-scissor-lift-legs-problem-with-constraints-and-parenting and a possible prototype: https://www.rtequipment.co.nz/products/double-scissor-lift-tables-models-2e-2a

Comment: hello again ron. yes i have the autocad file wher i exported the file from and i can also provide you the blender file and autocad file.  but i scale the size down to 0.000237 from autocad to blender when i do the import in blender

Comment: https://www.scribd.com/doc/95476293/Simulative-Calculation-and-Optimal-Design-of-Scissor-Lift-Mechanism in figure 2 it shows the hydraulic cylinder on the fixed pivot. Yours seems to be on the moving pivot side?

Comment: i did not use pivot point for the hydraulic cylinders. i youse 1 bone paired to the scissor frame then second bone is paired to the scissor frame bone with free transform enabel and also paired to the cylinder or piston. and the same at opposite side. and then last the bone parent with cylinder and piston is traced to each other by contraint. the track to just cant keep up doing the job aming at the right 3d curser point i put dead center at the hook point on cylinder and piston when is hook on the frame part

Comment: i rig cylinder and piston this way in the youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e2a5mCa2Hj4&t=449s

Comment: the blender file can be downloaded here https://wetransfer.com/downloads/774231aa42926ade7460b74a208a4b5820200814055454/1012ba59e4c70245a4a030b935404d2b20200814055510/c9d852 i tried using empties following the video but i really cant make it work

Answer (score 1):

Markom3D has recently done a small YouTube series on modelling and rigging a SciFi landing gear [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1DrFRqy1K5VdJsPc2py2tM6zNKi2xL6u). He explains how he modelled the pistons at 6 minutes in part 1 and how the model is rigged in the final part called 'How to rig a SciFi landing gear'.
Hope that is of some help.